# Convert via reflection retrieved object to string (how to iterate over multiple class types?)

Tags: java, class, parsing, reflection, instanceof

I have a getterMethod that returns an type which I retrieve using:

```
getterMethod.getReturnType()
```

I need to cast this return value to string. Depending on the type of the returned value, I either need to just use `.toString()` method on the object, sometimes I need to do more work like using a stringformat for dates etc..

I couldn't help myself but going this way:

```
Integer i = 1;
if(i.getClass().isInstance(getterMethod.getReturnType())){
    // integer to string
}
```

But I have lots of possible types, what would be a good and fast approach to resolve this?

Is it possible to use switch case blocks on class-types?

Comment: You can write `getterMethod.getReturnType() == Integer.class`, To convert to a String you can call `toString()` and this wlll work well for many types.

Comment: when I got a date-object for example I need this in a very special format. simply using .tostring is a nogo thats why I started the question ;)

Comment: A thought, can we do something like: `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); sb.append(anything); String result = sb.toString();`. You have to tweak it for specific date format though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the hierarchic character and inheritance some verbosity will remain.

Object oriented would be a map.

```
Class<?> clazz = getterMethod.getReturnType();
```

> Note that already here inheritance is cruel: a child class may return
>   a derived class of the return type in the super class; and have both
>   getter methods for the same signature.

You will probably need to handle Class.isPrimitive (`Integer.class` and `int.class`) with respect to the value received from the getter.

Also `Class.isArrayType` and such.

But a map of type converters is feasible:

```
Map<Class<?>, Function<Object, String>> map;

Function<Object, String> converter;
do {
     converter = map.get(clazz);
     clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
} while (converter == null && clazz != null;

String asText = converter == null
    ? String.valueOf(value)
    : converter.apply(value);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can do the following:

```
String objectCLassName = obj.class.getName();
```

This is the string of the class name of a generic object.

If your method returns a string simply compare it with this one.

For example

```
String returnType = getterMethod.getReturnType();
if (i.class.getName().equals(returnType)) {
    // Your code here
}
```